# Como verificar se existe atualização no google play para minha aplicação

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Tenho um app publicado no google play, onde agora estou com a necessidade de verificar se existe uma atualização pra ele, caso exista eu preciso fazer uma rotina. Existe essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 0):

Se tu usa Firebase pode colocar a variavel da versão nele pelo meio das `Functions`, depois no seu app vc pode usar o `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` pra fazer a comparação!

Caso vc não use o Firebase, faça um endpoint no seu backend que retorne a versão mais recente do app.

Comment: então... eu estou usando AWS ai não encontrei uma forma ideal de resolver isso. Eu tive que fazer a segunda opção que você sugeriu. Criei um endpoint e sempre consumo ele.

Comment: @RenanSilva Se a resposta te ajudou marque-a como útil. Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, no Google IO 2019 a google liberou essa api para implementação. 
Ela se chama **[in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)** Tudo que precisa fazer é implementar ela no seu aplicativo. 
Lembrando que esse novo formato de atualização está disponível a partir do  Android 5.0 (API level 21).

Artigo do [mindorks](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-in-app-updates-on-android) com detalhes sobre a implementação.